# Will the dynamic fee algorithm under development be a wallet side calculation or it will be a consensus rule?

Tags: transaction-fees

Will the dynamic fee algorithm under development be a wallet side calculation or it will be a consensus rule?

I ask that question because if the dynamic fee algorithm is a censensus code rule, making adjustments on it will require hard/soft fork and that sounds more troublesome than if the fee were just calculated by the wallet.

Comment: Just in case you are not aware, Monero is hard forked every 6 months, so it wouldn't be as troublesome as you might think.

Comment: Well soft/hard fork might become harder in the future and it might become hard to find consensus of network fee. Then we might end in a Bitcoin like crisis..

Answer (score 6):

Since the 2014 attack the fee where forced by miners. The calculation for the dynamic fee will be made on the wallet side, and then verified by the miners and if it is on the miners default it will be acepted by the network

Note by tewinget: "the network doesn't care about fees for a block, but miners do care about tx fees when deciding which to include in a block"

Answer (score 2):

The dynamic fee calculation will most probably be a wallet side thing, as the per kB calculation currently is.

The intent of the dynamic fees is to adapt the fees paid to the block size and block reward, so that the fees paid by a transaction can pay for any penalty that a miner may incur  when adding a transaction to an already nominal sized block. This does not strictly require the fees to be part of the consensus rules, since a monetary incentive will be there to get an equilibrium through self interest.